# How to create a dynamic property value in an OSGi DS service registration

Tags: osgi, cxf

Here's a bit of code from the Apache CXF documentation:

```
CustomMessageBodyReaderWriter provider1 = new CustomMessageBodyReaderWriter();
provider.setCustomProperty(true);

Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.provider", provider);

bundleContext.registerService(
   new String[]{"org.books.BookService"}, new BookServiceImpl(), properties);
```

Note that this piece of an activator method registers an OSGi service where one of the property values is an object created and configured at runtime.

Now, what if I wanted this to be a CXF dOSGi component? The only way I know to specify service registration properties for DS @Components requires the property value to be a string in the 'properties' slot in the `@Component`. Is there some way to have executable code involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CXF is not using the service properties correctly. The spec says :

> Properties hold information as key/value pairs. The key must be a
>   String object and the value should be a type recognized by Filter
>   objects (see Filters on page 138 for a list). Multiple values for the
>   same key are supported with arrays ([]) and Collection objects. The
>   values of properties should be limited to primitive or standard Java
>   types to prevent unwanted inter bundle dependencies. ...
>
> The service properties are intended to provide information about the
>   service. The properties should not be used to participate in the
>   actual function of the service. Modifying the properties for the
>   service registration is a potentially expensive operation. For
>   example, a Framework may pre-process the properties into an index
>   during registration to speed up later look-ups.

Anyway, AFAIK, it's not possible with the current DS to create such properties. You can however :

- The 'DS way', use an immediate component which creates the real component with a [ComponentFactory](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentFactory.html)
- Use an immediate component, and register your service with the raw osgi API
- If you use felix SCR, you can use a [ExtComponentContext](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/scr/1.6.2/org/apache/felix/scr/component/ExtComponentContext.html) to override your component properties

**Update:**

an example of a ComponentFactory :

```
@Component(factory = "bookService")
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
  ...
}
```

And a component using this factory :

```
@Component
public class BookServiceManager {

  @Reference(target = "(component.factory=bookService)")
  private ComponentFactory bookServiceFactory;

  @Activate
  public void start() {
    CustomMessageBodyReaderWriter provider1 = new CustomMessageBodyReaderWriter();
    provider.setCustomProperty(true);

    Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.provider", provider);

    bookServiceFactory.newInstance(properties);
  }
}
```

To be honest, with this use-case, I prefer using the raw OSGi API. But this approach can be useful if you want DS to manage your @Reference in your ComponentFactory. When the dependencies are not satisfied, the ComponentFactory and all its ComponentInstance will be deactivated.

Comment: I don't suppose you could point to an example of the ComponentFactory way of doing things.

Comment: @bmargulies I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Pretty cool. I did not find the ComponentFactory in the DS examples.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a 2.0 version of CXF-DOSGi which will allow to set provder instances as intents. You can then publish an instance of CustomMessageBodyReaderWriter under an intent name and refer to it from your remote service by listing the required intents.

Comment: OK. I guess I can make subclasses for now. I've got some other questions for you over on the CXF user list :-).